# BLE_UUID16_DECLARE issues

Tags: c++, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp-idf, arduino-esp32

Hi I am trying to do a simple test on ble with esp32 for gatt. I get errors from compiler that are not for my .cpp and .hpp but for the esp-idf which should not happen. I suppose that something exists in my files which is misleading the compiler.

I am using esp-idf = v4.4 , vscode espressif plugin 1.2

So the problem is on BLE_UUID16_DECLARE.

My code now is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "nvs_flash.h"
#include "esp_log.h"
#include "esp_nimble_hci.h"
#include "nimble/nimble_port.h"
#include "nimble/nimble_port_freertos.h"
#include "host/ble_hs.h"
#include "services/gap/ble_svc_gap.h"
#include "services/gatt/ble_svc_gatt.h"
#include "host/ble_uuid.h"
#include "myBle.hpp"

#define DEVICE_NAME "My BLE Device"

#define DEV_INFO 0x180A
#define MANUFACTURER 0x2A29
uint8_t ble_address_type;

const ble_uuid_t* devInfoUuid= BLE_UUID16_DECLARE(DEV_INFO);
const ble_uuid_t* manufacturerUuid= BLE_UUID16_DECLARE(MANUFACTURER);

static int device_info(uint16_t conn_handle, uint16_t attr_handle, struct ble_gatt_access_ctxt *ctxt, void *arg){

    os_mbuf_append(ctxt->om,"Achieved",strlen("Achieved"));
    return 0;
}

const struct ble_gatt_chr_def gatt_chrs[]={
    {
        .uuid = manufacturerUuid,
        .access_cb = device_info,
        .flags = BLE_GATT_CHR_F_READ
    },
    {
        0
    }
};

static const struct ble_gatt_svc_def gat_svcs[]= {
    {
        .type = BLE_GATT_SVC_TYPE_PRIMARY,
        .uuid = devInfoUuid,
        .characteristics =  gatt_chrs
        
    },
    {
        0,
    }
};
```

I had the creation of the struct also in once block initially but the issue was the same. code was like this:

```
#define DEV_INFO 0x180A
#define MANUFACTURER 0x2A29
 
 
static int device_info(uint16_t conn_handle, uint16_t attr_handle, struct ble_gatt_access_ctxt *ctxt, void *arg){
 
    os_mbuf_append(ctxt->om,"Achieved",strlen("Achieved"));
    return 0;
}
 
 
static const struct ble_gatt_svc_def gat_svcs[] = {
    {
        .type = BLE_GATT_SVC_TYPE_PRIMARY,
        .uuid = BLE_UUID16_DECLARE(DEV_INFO),
        .characteristics = (struct ble_gatt_chr_def[])
        {
            {
                .uuid = BLE_UUID16_DECLARE(MANUFACTURER),
                .access_cb = device_info,
                .flags = BLE_GATT_CHR_F_READ
            },
            {
                0,
            },
        }
    },
    {
        0,
    },
};
```

I also tried to put the defined hex inside the function immediately but result is the same.

The errors are on the `BLE_UUID16_DECLARE` in the problems tab:

> [{ "resource":
> "/Users/kyrpav/workspace/esp32/tutorials/LearnEsp32/main/Lesson12/myBle.cpp",
> "owner": "C/C++", "code": "18", "severity": 8, "message": "expected a
> ')'", "source": "C/C++", "startLineNumber": 29, "startColumn": 17,
> "endLineNumber": 29, "endColumn": 35 }]

Second error on the same part is:

> [{ "resource":
> "/Users/kyrpav/workspace/esp32/tutorials/LearnEsp32/main/Lesson12/myBle.cpp",
> "owner": "cpp", "severity": 8, "message": "expected declaration before
> '}' token", "startLineNumber": 41, "startColumn": 5, "endLineNumber":
> 41, "endColumn": 5 }]

if you check the terminal you see:

> /Users/kyrpav/esp/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/include/host/ble_uuid.h:102:36:
> error: expected primary-expression before ')' token ((ble_uuid_t *)
> (&(ble_uuid16_t) BLE_UUID16_INIT(uuid16))) ^
> ../main/Lesson12/myBle.cpp:19:32: note: in expansion of macro
> 'BLE_UUID16_DECLARE' const ble_uuid_t* devInfoUuid=
> BLE_UUID16_DECLARE(DEV_INFO); ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> /Users/kyrpav/esp/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/include/host/ble_uuid.h:84:5:
> error: expected ')' before '{' token { \ ^
> /Users/kyrpav/esp/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/include/host/ble_uuid.h:102:38:
> note: in expansion of macro 'BLE_UUID16_INIT' ((ble_uuid_t *)
> (&(ble_uuid16_t) BLE_UUID16_INIT(uuid16))) ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ../main/Lesson12/myBle.cpp:19:32: note: in expansion of macro
> 'BLE_UUID16_DECLARE' const ble_uuid_t* devInfoUuid=
> BLE_UUID16_DECLARE(DEV_INFO); ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> /Users/kyrpav/esp/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/include/host/ble_uuid.h:102:21:
> note: to match this '(' ((ble_uuid_t *) (&(ble_uuid16_t)
> BLE_UUID16_INIT(uuid16))) ^ ../main/Lesson12/myBle.cpp:19:32: note: in
> expansion of macro 'BLE_UUID16_DECLARE' const ble_uuid_t* devInfoUuid=
> BLE_UUID16_DECLARE(DEV_INFO); ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> /Users/kyrpav/esp/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/include/host/ble_uuid.h:102:36:
> error: expected primary-expression before ')' token ((ble_uuid_t *)
> (&(ble_uuid16_t) BLE_UUID16_INIT(uuid16))) ^
> ../main/Lesson12/myBle.cpp:20:37: note: in expansion of macro
> 'BLE_UUID16_DECLARE' const ble_uuid_t* manufacturerUuid=
> BLE_UUID16_DECLARE(MANUFACTURER); ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> /Users/kyrpav/esp/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/include/host/ble_uuid.h:84:5:
> error: expected ')' before '{' token { \ ^
> /Users/kyrpav/esp/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/include/host/ble_uuid.h:102:38:
> note: in expansion of macro 'BLE_UUID16_INIT' ((ble_uuid_t *)
> (&(ble_uuid16_t) BLE_UUID16_INIT(uuid16))) ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> ../main/Lesson12/myBle.cpp:20:37: note: in expansion of macro
> 'BLE_UUID16_DECLARE' const ble_uuid_t* manufacturerUuid=
> BLE_UUID16_DECLARE(MANUFACTURER); ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> /Users/kyrpav/esp/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/include/host/ble_uuid.h:102:21:
> note: to match this '(' ((ble_uuid_t *) (&(ble_uuid16_t)
> BLE_UUID16_INIT(uuid16))) ^ ../main/Lesson12/myBle.cpp:20:37: note: in
> expansion of macro 'BLE_UUID16_DECLARE' const ble_uuid_t*
> manufacturerUuid= BLE_UUID16_DECLARE(MANUFACTURER);

It seems that I found the real cause of the problem.

And the cause is

```
extern "C"
{
    void app_main();
}
```

The project that I have is in cpp and I am using in normal way the `extern` functionality.

I have created a new project in .c and everything worked. As second step i even placed the ble code in different .c and .h file
and it worked fine.

Then I renamed the files to cpp and hpp and fix Makefile and on build I get the same error:

```
../main/myBle.cpp:34:17: note: in expansion of macro
'BLE_UUID16_DECLARE'
         .uuid = BLE_UUID16_DECLARE(DEVICE_INFO_SERVICE),
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/kyrpav/esp/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/include/host/ble_uuid.h:84:5:
error: expected ')' before '{' token
     {                                   \
     ^ /Users/kyrpav/esp/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/include/host/ble_uuid.h:103:38:
note: in expansion of macro 'BLE_UUID16_INIT'
     ((ble_uuid_t *) (&(ble_uuid16_t) BLE_UUID16_INIT(uuid16)))
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ../main/myBle.cpp:34:17: note: in expansion of macro
'BLE_UUID16_DECLARE'
         .uuid = BLE_UUID16_DECLARE(DEVICE_INFO_SERVICE),
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/kyrpav/esp/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/include/host/ble_uuid.h:103:21:
note: to match this '('
     ((ble_uuid_t *) (&(ble_uuid16_t) BLE_UUID16_INIT(uuid16)))
                     ^ ../main/myBle.cpp:34:17: note: in expansion of macro 'BLE_UUID16_DECLARE'
         .uuid = BLE_UUID16_DECLARE(DEVICE_INFO_SERVICE),
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/kyrpav/esp/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/include/host/ble_uuid.h:103:62:
error: expected '}' before ')' token
     ((ble_uuid_t *) (&(ble_uuid16_t) BLE_UUID16_INIT(uuid16)))
                                                              ^ ../main/myBle.cpp:34:17: note: in expansion of macro
'BLE_UUID16_DECLARE'
         .uuid = BLE_UUID16_DECLARE(DEVICE_INFO_SERVICE),
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ../main/myBle.cpp:32:5: note: to match this '{'
     {
     ^ In file included from /Users/kyrpav/esp/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/include/host/ble_hs_adv.h:24,
                 from /Users/kyrpav/esp/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/include/host/ble_gap.h:32,
                 from /Users/kyrpav/esp/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/include/host/ble_hs.h:33,
                 from ../main/myBle.cpp:7: /Users/kyrpav/esp/esp-idf/components/bt/host/nimble/nimble/nimble/host/include/host/ble_uuid.h:103:62:
error: expected '}' before ')' token
     ((ble_uuid_t *) (&(ble_uuid16_t) BLE_UUID16_INIT(uuid16)))
                                                              ^ ../main/myBle.cpp:34:17: note: in expansion of macro
'BLE_UUID16_DECLARE'
         .uuid = BLE_UUID16_DECLARE(DEVICE_INFO_SERVICE),
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ../main/myBle.cpp:31:51: note: to match this '{'  static const struct ble_gatt_svc_def gat_svcs[] = {
                                                   ^ ../main/myBle.cpp:47:5: error: expected declaration before '}' token
     },
     ^ ../main/myBle.cpp:24:12: warning: 'int device_info(uint16_t, uint16_t, ble_gatt_access_ctxt*, void*)' defined but not used
[-Wunused-function]  static int device_info(uint16_t conn_handle,
uint16_t attr_handle, struct ble_gatt_access_ctxt *ctxt, void *arg)
            ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: compiler errors are expected to be formatted as code because they're properly aligned to show where the errors are and won't be readable without proper formatting

Answer (score 1):

Sadly nimble code can't be compiled with C++ out of the box. It makes heavy use of designated initializers and compound literals, two features with subtle differences between C and C++.

Specially the latter is a real pain and takes some boilerplate code to work around. The reason can be found on the gcc docs on [compound literals](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html).

> In C, a compound literal designates an unnamed object with static or
> automatic storage duration. In C++, a compound literal designates a
> temporary object that only lives until the end of its full-expression.
> As a result, well-defined C code that takes the address of a subobject
> of a compound literal can be undefined in C++, so G++ rejects the
> conversion of a temporary array to a pointer. For instance, if the
> array compound literal example above appeared inside a function, any
> subsequent use of foo in C++ would have undefined behavior because the
> lifetime of the array ends after the declaration of foo.

Pulling the BLE service characteristics out of the service struct as you've done in your first example should be sufficient to work around the issue though.

For the UUID macros you could replace the ones from nimble with some which are C++ compliant. E.g. the macro for the UUID16 could be something along the lines of

```
#define UUID16(uuid16)                                                         \
  std::invoke([] {                                                             \
    static constexpr ble_uuid16_t uuid{.u = BLE_UUID_TYPE_16,                  \
                                       .value = uuid16};                       \
    return std::bit_cast<ble_uuid_t*>(&uuid);                                  \
  })
```